# Laravel file cache on Heroku. How to keep them after pushes?

Tags: caching, laravel, heroku

If you use Heroku to host a Laravel app, you probably know what happens if you use the file cache. After every git push, it will be gone. That sucks if you need to cache something forever.

Do you know any method to work around that? Or should I just pick another cache driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use files for this, sorry.

Pick any other [add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/) for caching.