# One deploying my laravel 8 app to Heroku I run into Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, windows-10, laravel-8

I know this problem is very similar to existing ones here, except that I have created all the folders needed within storage and still doesn't work. I wonder if anyone is facing the same issue...

`Please provide a valid cache path.` Laravel 8, Heroku, and all done in Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel file cache on Heroku. How to keep them after pushes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622168/laravel-file-cache-on-heroku-how-to-keep-them-after-pushes)

Comment: @chris this time it didn't help as I am using windows instead of linux.

Comment: Your local operating system has nothing to do with it. You can't use a file-based cache on Heroku. Instead, pick another [back-end](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#driver-prerequisites) (database, Memcached, or Redis should work), provision an appropriate add-on, and away you go.